# Animate CSS not working

Tags: css, animated, animate.css

I am trying to add animate.css into my website. For this I am trying out with a basic example.

```
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css">
  <h1 class="animated infinite bounce">Animate</h1>
</html>
```

But its not working. The path is absolutely correct. And I am working in XAMPP.

Comment: Renderable elements should be placed in a <body> tag

Answer (score 5):

The `link` tag has to be inside the `head` element.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="animated infinite bounce">Animate</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its still not working... is it due to use of localhost ?

Comment: try doing it without the localhost. Just open the file straight in your browser. animate.css is in the same directory as your html file?

Comment: Its working now, by just opening the html file in a browser. Why is it not working in localhost ?

Comment: Maybe your localhost isn't working correctly. When you right-click > view source, do you see the html?

Comment: Yeah i do see the html

Comment: The new or old HTML? Try ./animate.css instead

Comment: New html. I downloaded a template which has animated bounce in it. It works fine in localhost

Comment: Don't know what to tell you